# Three.js Strange pixel trail on Firefox

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

I'm experiencing a strange issue just on Firefox* where my stage is not cleared before rendering and I get a "pixel trail" under my animated mesh.

Here is a screenshot of what happens. 
(The mesh is the one on top with the "2" texture and is a cube which rotates on the X axis by pressing the black "up" and "down" buttons)
[image]

What could the cause be?

*(I haven't found what's common with the browsers this happens in, the version can change for example)

EDIT:

Here is a link to the live example. I repeat that it doesn't happen on a specific Firefox version.
http://clients.weborama.nl/files/campaigns2/4578609654/76560/IT_repubblica.it_201401_index.html

I can surely tell that the Firefox where I see this issue has these properties:
[image]

Comment: Looks like the framebuffer isn't being cleared at all. Are you using autoClear and/or preserveDrawingBuffer anywhere in your code?

Comment: no, should I use them?

Comment: No, the defaults are to clear the buffer each frame. Interesting issue. If no one has a better suggestion, I'd suggest posting a link to a reproduction case. I'm sure we'd all be happy to take a look.

Comment: edited adding link to live example and more information on the browser I see the issue on

Comment: I suspect that this issue is only reproducible with a particular graphics card/graphics card driver - it likely has a bug that other browsers work around. `about:support` page lists graphics info, have a look and compare the problematic configurations.

Comment: I cannot duplicate this issue in your live example. Did you correct this already?

Comment: I worked around it by using the Canvas Engine on Firefox